# $wpdb->insert with WordPress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using WordPress shortcode with $wpdb->insert. It works, but it runs TWICE.

```
function f_registrazione()
{

    $output = '';
    if(!$_POST['txtNome'])
    {
        $output .= "do something in html";
    } else {
        $output .= "do something else in html";
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( mg_nomi, array('des_nome' => $_POST['txtNome']) );
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'registrazione', 'f_registrazione' );
```

This function is written in a custom file linked to them's functions.php

What's wrong? I've already tried different solutions, none work.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 ); 

wp_reset_postdata();

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Have you called the shortcode twice?

Comment: No, only once in one page...

Comment: I've added

echo $ wpdb-> insert_id;

before return $output;

it returns "1" in the top of the page, and "2" in the right place.

Comment: where you are using this shortcode `registrazione`?

Comment: Oh, are you working online or on localhost? If online, can you share your URL to look into?

Comment: `$wpdb->insert_id` should ALWAYS return `false` or `1`, so there is a weird thing here. Did you check in the database if there is two entries ?

Comment: @Vel and Mohammad: here is the production page: http://www.matteogandini.it/prove

Comment: @Alex yes checked the db and I confirm double entries

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?